# AppleScript : use variable to call safari tab

Tags: terminal, applescript, safari

how can I refer to a safari tab using a variable ?
this code find the tab I want across all safari windows and tabs

```
    set winmatchlist to {}
set tabmatchlist to {}
set tabnamematchlist to {}


tell application "Safari"
    repeat with w in windows
        repeat with t in tabs of w
            if (URL of t) contains "https://www.google.com/demo/" then
                set end of winmatchlist to w
                set end of tabmatchlist to t
                set end of tabnamematchlist to (id of w as string) & "." & 2 & ".  " & (name of t as string)
                set windowid to (id of w as string)
                
                
                ##return "Tab id: " & tabId & "Window id: " & windowId
            end if
        end repeat
    end repeat
    set w to item 1 of winmatchlist
    set t to item 1 of tabmatchlist
    #set current tab of w to t
    #set index of w to 1
end tell

##return tabnamematchlist


set URLadd to "https://www.google.com"
tell application "Safari"
    tell window id windowid -- the correct safari window
        set URL of tab t to URLadd -- change the URL of the second tab
        
    end tell
end tell
```

this first line set the correct window but **set URL of tab t** doens't work
tell window id windowid -- the correct safari window
set URL of tab t to URLadd -- change the URL of the second tab

Comment: Note that `w` and `t` are already references to the object.

Comment: I think I missing the obvious but when I refer to tab id t I have an error "Safari got an error: Can’t make item 2 of every window into type integer."

Comment: Since `w` and `t` already refer to the window and tab, you can just do `tell application "Safari" to tell w to set URL of t to URLadd`. (And in this case you don’t even need to use the window, as that is in the tab reference)